# Find parameters to maximise output score

Tags: optimization

Not sure this is the right place to ask. Lets say there is a function `f()` where its implementation is unknown but it returns a score. I would like to get the highest possible score by modifying the input parameters. I also try to be better than brute force (finding all possible combination of input parameters, if that is even possible)

I do know that

- `f()` runs an algorithm against a known dataset. The algorithm is tweaked by the input parameters.
- `f()` needs 6 parameters
- I know the type of each parameter (int, float, boolean)
- I know the range of each parameter i.e [-1,5](int), [0,1](float, percentage, i.e 0.5 = 50%)
- Some parameters have an open range i.e >1 (int)
- Some are dependent of each other. i.e min and max parameter. That is min < max.

Any good pointers to algorithms that could help me solve that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the objective/loss function here?

Comment: @Peter: I think OP defines `f` as the objective function, the unknown function which returns a score.

Comment: correct as @Erwan said. f() returns a score that I try to maximise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this kind of optimization problem a [genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) is often a good approach, assuming computing the value of  `f()` is not too costly.

The idea is to represent the 6 parameters as "genes". In the first generation their values are assigned randomly, then each "individual" in the generation (combination of parameters) is evaluated (i.e. calculate `f`), and the top performing "individuals" are selected. The next generation is obtained by cross-over and random mutation, and the process is repeated until `f` converges to a maximum.

Comment: Thanks @Erwan . Interesting approach indeed. `f()` cost is mainly time as it takes about 5-10 seconds to compute. Do you maybe know some library for python? I did find tpot but it seems to be used for ML algorithms

Comment: @Chris I don't know any python library but I can see that searching "python genetic search" returns many results which seem relevant. In the past I implemented my own genetic algorithm, it's not very complex and this way I can control everything.

Comment: the difficulty I have is how to find top performing individuals since `f()` is a blackbox function.

Comment: @Chris in this context an individual is an assignment of all 6 parameters. If you have the values of the 6 parameters you can calculate f, right?

Comment: yes correct. I get a score if I have all 6 parameters. So if I do a batch with random assignment then I pick the most performing set of parameters and do the cross-over and random mutation?